# How to find this reference ExceptionManager.LogException in C#?

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

I have a piece of code that I got from MSDN and I am not sure how do I reference this class?

It mentioned about Exception Management Application Block ... is this an old version of Ms Enterprise Library?

```
catch (Exception generalException)
{
    ExceptionManager.LogException(generalException);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Exception Management Application Block does have a type named ExceptionManager, but it has no such method like LogException, it has overloaded method HandleException instead. Read [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.exceptionhandling.exceptionmanager_members(v=PandP.50).aspx) for more details